# Missing div borders

Tags: html, css

I need your help,

It seems that I am having some difficulty with attempting to add a div around a textarea inside a container div as well as a border for the div encompassing my button at the bottom of the container div.

First problem: the right side border is missing

Second problem, the 1px solid red is missing from the inner2 div.

Here is a pic of the problem and the desired result:

[image]

Desired result is:

[image]

Here is the HTML & CSS in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<style type="text/css">
#container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid green;

}
#summary {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%; 
    border: 0;
}

#inner1 {
    height: 500px;
}

#inner2 {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>

<div id="container">


        <div id='inner1'><textarea id="summary"></textarea></div>


    <div id="inner2"><input type="button" value="Close"></div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the `textarea` element has default padding. Since padding isn't included in an element's width/height calculations, it overflows outside of the parent element because a width of `100%` + the border is greater than the parent elements width.

You could either remove this padding, or include the padding in the dimension calculations by adding [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to the `textarea` element:

```
#summary {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` and `box-sizing: border-box;` like below:

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid green;

}
#summary {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%; 
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#inner1 {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#inner2 {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}
```